# Syntax errors in vue.js code for autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

hi I'm trying to [autocomplete/typeahead component for Vue 2 and Bootstrap 4](https://vuejsexamples.com/an-autocomplete-typeahead-component-for-vue-2-and-bootstrap-4/)
This is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-bootstrap-typeahead/dist/VueBootstrapTypeahead.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">
            <vue-bootstrap-typeahead 
                v-model="query"
                :data="['Canada', 'USA', 'Mexico']" />
        </div>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.10/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-bootstrap-typeahead"></script>
        <script>
            import VueBootstrapTypeahead from 'vue-bootstrap-typeahead';
            Vue.component('vue-bootstrap-typeahead', VueBootstrapTypeahead);

            new Vue({
                el: '#container',
                data: {
                    value: '',
                },
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this is not working due to following errors.

> **SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**
>
> Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL:
> https://unpkg.com/vue-bootstrap-typeahead Source Map URL:
> VueBootstrapTypeahead.umd.min.js.map

It would be great if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Please add this to the `<head>` of your document before the `<link>` tags: `<meta charset="UTF-8"> `

Comment: thanks bro I added it

Comment: No problem. It was an educated guess. Since it is working I posted it as an answer.

Comment: sure but I need SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module to be removed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-bootstrap-typeahead"></script>` has imported the `VueBootstrapTypeahead`, and became a property of window.You don't need `import` again. when we talk about `import`, often the `module` concert come to us too. `import` declarations was often used in an app which need be transformed by tools, such as `babel`,`webpack` or `rollup`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I did it and all errors gone but autocomplete element is not appearing :'(

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to the `<head>` of your document before the `<link>` tags:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```